# Can the body always find the right antibodies?

Tags: antibody

If the body produces random antibodies in order to fight a virus, is there a small chance that the specific antibody needed to fight the virus just won't be randomly generated? Even though it is a common virus that normally doesn't kill people?

For example if you have a common cold, is there a small chance that you could die from this just by probability? Whereas someone else won't because they randomly produced the right antibody?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. Yes, it's possible that some individuals won't be able to (or happen to) make antibodies to a specific part of a pathogen. But most pathogens are large and complex enough that they have many different targets for antibodies, and it becomes increasingly unlikely that someone won't be able to target *any* part of the pathogen.

An example is given in [Influence of Immune Priming and Egg Adaptation in the Vaccine on Antibody Responses to Circulating A(H1N1)pdm09 Viruses After Influenza Vaccination in Adults](https://academic.oup.com/jid/article/218/10/1571/5042019). A subset of adults (who were exposed to a particular influenza virus as children) have poor antibody responses to a vaccine to a different strain of influenza virus:

> Significantly reduced antibody reactivity to circulating viruses bearing K163Q was observed only in the USSR/77-primed cohort, whereas significantly lower reactivity caused by egg-adapted Q223R change was detected across all 3 cohorts.

(This is not an argument against vaccination, I feel obliged to point out, because the vaccinated people were still better off than unvaccinated, just not as well protected as they could be.)